# Does functions inside anononymus functions ("callbacks") gets redefined in memory on each callback?

Tags: javascript, callback, closures, anonymous-function

If you define a function inside an anonymous function, for example a "callback" function used as an argument. Let's take `Array.prototype.forEach` for example:

```
['one','two','three'].forEach (function(item) {
  function showValue(i) {
    console.log (i);
  }
  showValue(item);
});
```

Will the function `showValue` be "redefined" 3 times?

If we write that code in this variation:

```
function handleItem(item) {
  function showValue(i) {
    console.log (i);
  }
  showValue(item);
}
['one','two','three'].forEach (handleItem);
```

Is there a difference? memory-wise or otherwise.

What about this variation:

```
var handleItem = (function(item) {

  function showValue(i) {
    console.log (i);
  }

  return function(item) {
    showValue(item);
  }

})();


['one','two','three'].forEach (handleItem);
```

Which I guess is a more "proper" closure. 
Will this have any difference?

Comment: Just do `function showValue(i){…}` `[…].forEach(function handleItem(item) { showValue(item); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the function showValue be "redefined" 3 times?

In theory, yes. In practice, JavaScript engines are *really smart*. If you literally do what you've shown, the engine will almost certainly optimize the function out entirely, inlining its code. If the function is more complex and not amenable to inlining, the engine will still probably compile the function once and just change out its context on each iteration.

> Is there a difference? memory-wise or otherwise.

Only a small one: You'll still have the `handleItem` function in memory after the iteration completes. In terms of `showItem`, nothing changes.

> What about this variation? Which I guess is a more "proper" closure.

You'll have `handleItem` after the iteration completes, and all iterations will use the same `showItem`, which will also still exist after iteration completes. (Side note: The `item` in `var handleItem = (function(item) {` is misleading, you aren't accepting an `item` there.)

---

> Do you think one of the variations is "better" somehow than the rest?

For me, given the code in the question, the answer is "none of the above." Instead:

```
['one', 'two', 'three'].forEach(function(i) {
    console.log(i);
});
```

I don't think there's really a general case answer. It totally depends on what `handleItem` and `showItem` actually do, how complex they are, whether you're going to reuse them, whether `showItem` needs to do things that are specific to a given call to `handleItem` (other than that the item varies), etc., etc.

Comment: Do you think one of the variations is "better" somehow than the rest?

Comment: @YuvalA.: I've updated the answer to address that question.